# Child div with high z-index not workin

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs (black-to-transparent, slider and redBox) set up like this:

```
<div class="black-to-transparent">
  <div class="vertical-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="slider" style="image-size:cover;">
  <div id="text">
  <p>
  Why does this text go behind a div with a lower z-index, I want it above the white line, but it has to stay in the slide.
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="redBox" style="height:300px; width:100%; background-color:red;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#text {
    color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    background: transparent;

  }

  .vertical-line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 75px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
  }

  .black-to-transparent {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49.9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50.1%);
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    z-index: 5;
  }
```

`black-to-transparent` has a higher z-index than `slider` but `redBox` has a higher z-index than all of them. Somehow `redBox` still appears behind `black-to-transparent`. Is this because its a child of a div with a lower z-index than the div above?

And how can I solve this.

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e35xu520/5/

Comment: can you add your css to the question?

Comment: Please prepare a js fiddle with the whole html and css, otherwise we can't reproduce the error / mistake

Comment: give me a couple of mins lemme edit the post

Comment: @AnatPort added a js fiddle

Comment: @noa-dev js fiddle added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position: relative;` to your `#text` div like this:

```
#text {
    color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
}
```

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e35xu520/3/

Comment: Ur a hero! Accepting in a bit :)

Comment: @KevinAartsen Glad I could help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index):

> Each box belongs to one stacking context. Each positioned box in a given stacking context has an integer stack level, which is its position on the z-axis relative other stack levels within the same stacking context.

and

> stacking contexts are generated by any positioned element (including relatively positioned elements) having a computed value of 'z-index' other than 'auto'

Since you have given `2` it's own stacking context, the z-index you apply to `3` sets its position **inside** `2`.

You'd need to reorganise your markup so that `3` wasn't a descendant of `2`.

Answer (score 1):

`div3`'s higher z-index is working and is overlapping `div2` but since `div3`'s parent `div2` is stacked below `div1`, you can't see `div3` overlapping `div1` too unless you position `div2` on top of `div1`.

---

**tldr:** `div1` is in a certain position and `div3` is in another position. Hence, you obviously won't see `div3` overlapping `div1`.

---

Check code snippet below:

```css
.a1 {z-index:1;background-color: red;height:50px;width:50px;}
.a2 {z-index:0;background-color: green;height:50px;width:50px;}
.a3{z-index:2;background-color: blue;height:50px;width:50px;}
```

```html
<div class="a1">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
    <div class ="a3">
    </div>
    </div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/123/

---

**P.S.** Avoid starting `IDs` and `CLASSES` with numbers as that is bad practice. Always a letter or word before the number like I did above.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so ! I added a js fiddle mind looking at it?

Comment: @KevinAartsen Check the other answer.